# Pandas как получить ближайшую меньшую дату

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Дан df:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([{'b': 'Собака', 'c': 'Кот', 'd': 18.12.2012},
              {'b': 'Еж', 'c': 'Птица', 'd': 15.12.2012},
              {'b': 'Кот', 'c': 'Еж', 'd': 16.12.2012},
              {'b': 'Собака', 'c': 'Кот', 'd': 12.12.2012},
              {'b': 'Кот', 'c': 'Собака', 'd': 19.12.2012},

              {'b': 'Кот', 'c': 'Собака', 'd': 13.12.2012},
              {'b': 'Собака', 'c': 'Еж', 'd': 17.12.2012},
              {'b': 'Еж', 'c': 'Собака', 'd': 13.12.2012},
              {'b': 'Птица', 'c': 'Еж', 'd': 12.12.2012},
              {'b': 'Кот', 'c': 'Собака', 'd': 14.12.2012}])
```

Не могу понять как добавить новый столбец 'k', в котором бы отображалось количество дней до ближайшей предыдущей даты, в которой в столбце 'b' или 'c' == 'b' из рассматриваемой строки. На примере 4 строки, поясню: берем значение из столбца 'b', оно == 'Кот' и смотрим у него значение из 'd', далее ищем все строки, где либо значение столбца 'b' == 'Кот', либо значение 'с' == 'Кот' и смотрим у них тоже значения столбца 'd', далее из всех вариантов выбираем ближайшую меньшую дату и записываем ее в столбец 'k', то есть на примере 4 строки в нем окажется значение 1, так как самая ближайшая дата 18.12.2012 находится в 1 строке датасета и она на 1 день меньше нашей даты. Если меньшей даты не найдено, то 0.

То есть на выходе должно получится вот такое:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([{'b': 'Собака', 'c': 'Кот', 'd': 18.12.2012, 'k': 1},
              {'b': 'Еж', 'c': 'Птица', 'd': 15.12.2012, 'k': 2},
              {'b': 'Кот', 'c': 'Еж', 'd': 16.12.2012, 'k': 2},
              {'b': 'Собака', 'c': 'Кот', 'd': 12.12.2012, 'k': 0},
              {'b': 'Кот', 'c': 'Собака', 'd': 19.12.2012, 'k': 1},

              {'b': 'Кот', 'c': 'Собака', 'd': 13.12.2012, 'k': 1},
              {'b': 'Собака', 'c': 'Еж', 'd': 17.12.2012, 'k': 3},
              {'b': 'Еж', 'c': 'Собака', 'd': 13.12.2012, 'k': 1},
              {'b': 'Птица', 'c': 'Еж', 'd': 12.12.2012, 'k': 0},
              {'b': 'Кот', 'c': 'Собака', 'd': 14.12.2012, 'k': 1}])
```

На сколько я понимаю логика должна быть такой:

1. Получаем значение из столбца b - Х и из d - Y
2. Далее делаем query("b == Х"), берем все значения из d и вычитаем из даты полученной на предыдущем шаге Y каждое из них - запоминаем минимальное неотрицательное значение и не равное 0 (чтобы исключить нашу строку)
3. После делаем тоже самое, но query("с == Х"). Из двух полученных минимальное заносим в столбец k
4. если такового нет, то пишем 0

Возможно, есть более простой алгоритм действий, но проблема остается в том, что я не могу даже это написать на pandas..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как-то не очень понятно сформулирована задача, а пример данных на выходе ясности не добавляет (почему значения в столбцах таблицы на выходе поменялись?), но, как бы там ни было, возможно предложенный вариант решения натолкнет вас на идею:

```
# исходный датафрейм
'''
        b       c           d
0     Кот  Собака  18.12.2012
1      Еж   Птица  15.12.2012
2     Кот      Еж  14.12.2012
3  Собака     Кот  12.12.2012
4     Кот  Собака  12.12.2012
5     Кот  Собака  19.12.2012
6  Собака  Собака  17.12.2012
7      Еж  Собака  15.12.2012
8   Птица      Еж  12.12.2012
9     Кот  Собака  12.12.2012
'''

a['d'] = pd.to_datetime(a['d'])

k = []
for i,r in a.iterrows():
    df = a.drop(i)
    k.append(df[(df.b==r.b)|(df.c==r.b)]['d'].apply(lambda x: abs(x - r.d).days).min())

a = a.assign(k=k)

>>> a
# результат
'''
        b       c          d  k
0     Кот  Собака 2012-12-18  1
1      Еж   Птица 2012-12-15  0
2     Кот      Еж 2012-12-14  2
3  Собака     Кот 2012-12-12  0
4     Кот  Собака 2012-12-12  0
5     Кот  Собака 2012-12-19  1
6  Собака  Собака 2012-12-17  1
7      Еж  Собака 2012-12-15  0
8   Птица      Еж 2012-12-12  3
9     Кот  Собака 2012-12-12  0
```

**UPD (на комментарий)**

```
a['d'] = pd.to_datetime(a['d'])
k = []
for i,r in a.iterrows():
    df = a.drop(i)
    k.append(df[((df.b==r.b)|(df.c==r.b))&(df.d<r.d)]['d'].apply(lambda x: (r.d-x).days).min())
a = a.assign(k=k).fillna(0)

# результат
'''
        b       c          d  k
0  Собака     Кот 2012-12-18  1
1      Еж   Птица 2012-12-15  2
2     Кот      Еж 2012-12-16  2
3  Собака     Кот 2012-12-12  0
4     Кот  Собака 2012-12-19  1
5     Кот  Собака 2012-12-13  1
6  Собака      Еж 2012-12-17  3
7      Еж  Собака 2012-12-13  1
8   Птица      Еж 2012-12-12  0
9     Кот  Собака 2012-12-14  1
```

Comment: Сорри за ошибки в вопросе.. исправил. И спасибо большое за ответ, помогло.

Comment: есть проблема с abs, из-за него берется разница в днях как в большую так и меньшую сторону. А нужно выводить только разницу до ближайшей предыдущей даты. То есть если убрать abs, то брать только даты < 0, а потом их уже переводить в abs и брать минимальное число.

Comment: не знаете как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: @ChikChirik обновил свой ответ, пробуйте

Comment: Да, все ок, спасибо большое)